# Java SimpleDateFormat: Unparseable Date exception

Tags: java, simpledateformat

The code is as mentioned below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy");

    try{
        Date formattedDate = dateFormat.parse(date.toString());
        System.out.println(formattedDate.toString());
    }catch(ParseException parseEx){
        parseEx.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In code above, `dateFormat.parse(date.toString())` is throwing unparseable date exception: `Unparseable date: "Mon Jan 28 18:53:24 IST 2013`

I am not able to figure out the reason for it.

Comment: Are you trying to get the string representation of your date in the given format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to convert a date to a string and parse it back to a date?

The reason your code fails is because you are trying to convert a full date with a formatter which only accepts dates in the dd-MMM-yyy-format.

Comment: I wanted to check if formmattedDate.toString() will return  a full date or date in dd-MMM-yyyy format.

Comment: @kurt: I am facing same issue as you mentioned. I have to convert a full date: "2/18/2016 10:55:16 AM" into a format "EEE MMMMM dd, yyyy". It is giving me unaparseable Unparseable date Exception. What is the workaround?

Comment: If you have 'T' in date format (e.g. "2018-01-31T16:01:49") use this date format DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")

Answer (score 5):

Format the `java.util.Date` instance into String using `SimpleDateFormat.format(java.util.Date)`

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyy");

try {
    Date formattedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(date));
    System.out.println(formattedDate.toString());

} catch (ParseException parseEx) {
   parseEx.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

    Date formattedDate = dateFormat.parse(date.toString());
    System.out.println(formattedDate);

}
```

This is what you exactly want to do ...yes?