# ParseException involving SimpleDateFormat and Date

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I have this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date sDate = sParse.parse(startDate + " 00:00:00");
```

The above works fine when the value of `startDate` is in this format: "23-10-2014"

However my `startDate` is in this format: "23/10/2014", and I am getting:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "23/10/2014".
```

How do I overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java SimpleDateFormat: Unparseable Date exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563011/java-simpledateformat-unparseable-date-exception)

Answer (score 3):

You are asking compiler to parse the date dd-MM-yyyy and your are trying to send dd/MM/yyyy, So obviously it will throw parse error, If you don't know either which one of the format you input then use this code

```
    SimpleDateFormat sParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String startDate="23/10/2014".replace("/", "-");
    java.util.Date sDate = sParse.parse(startDate+ " 00:00:00");
    System.out.println(sDate);
```

For this either of the date format you can pass to get the output
23/10/2014
or
23-10-2014

Answer (score 1):

With the code `SimpleDateFormat sParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");`  you're telling the parser to expect the date to be formatted like 23-10-2014 (separated by -) so obviously it won't parse '23/10/2014'
For that you need to specify the format string as `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: Hi Maxaon, I did that too, as in I now used: 
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
and I still get a:
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "23/10/2014"

Comment: Works fine for me:
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String startDate= "23/10/2014";
        SimpleDateFormat sParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        java.util.Date sDate = sParse.parse(startDate + " 00:00:00");
    }

Did you forget to add " 00:00:00" to the end of the date?

Comment: Maxaon3000 you are right, I forgot to add it. It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you do not require to add the " 00:00:00" to the startDate string. Since, you are getting the hours, minute seconds value in your date String, it defaults to 0. You can remove the " hh:mm:ss" from pattern.

SimpleDateFormat sParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
java.util.Date sDate = sParse.parse(startDate + " 00:00:00");

thus as mentioned in the answer above, you can simply do:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sParse = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String startDate="23/10/2014".replace("/", "-");
    java.util.Date sDate = sParse.parse(startDate);
    System.out.println(sDate);
```