# How to check if time format is correct in Java (with Exception)

Tags: java, time, time-format

I'm working on a program that converts 24 hour time stamps into 12 hour time stamps. I managed to complete the conversion and loop it, but I need to code in an input validation that checks for incorrect inputs. An example of an incorrect input would be: "10:83" or "1):*2". Can someone show me how I can go about this using an Exception method? So far I have this:

```
public class conversion {

        public static void timeChange() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Enter time in 24hr format");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input1 = sc.nextLine();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm a");
            Date date = null;
            String timeOutput = null;

            date = df.parse(input1);
            timeOutput = df2.format(date);

            System.out.println("in 12 hour format: " + timeOutput);

            decision();
        }

        public static void decision() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Would you like to enter another time?");

            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userChoice = sc2.nextLine();

            while (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                timeChange();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            timeChange();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Some parse exception examples are found in the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563011/java-simpledateformat-unparseable-date-exception

Comment: Please don’t use the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 9):

Use `java.time` the modern Java date and time API for this.

For a slightly lenient validation:

```
    String inputTimeString = "10:83";
    try {
        LocalTime.parse(inputTimeString);
        System.out.println("Valid time string: " + inputTimeString);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException | NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid time string: " + inputTimeString);
    }
```

This will accept 09:41, 09:41:32 and even 09:41:32.46293846. But not 10:83, not 24:00 (should be 00:00) and not 9:00 (requires 09:00).

For stricter validation use an explicit formatter with the format you require:

```
    DateTimeFormatter strictTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

And pass it to the `parse`method:

```
        LocalTime.parse(inputTimeString, strictTimeFormatter);
```

Now also 09:41:32 gets rejected.

### Question: Can I use `java.time` with my Java version?

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the new API was forst described).
- On Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP, and there’s a thorough explanation in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

For learning to use `java.time`, see [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) or find other resoureces on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to match the required time and throw an IllegalArgumentException?

```
if(! input1.matches("(?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5]\\d")){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("The time you entered was not valid");
    }
```

Comment: the regex above wont work with 24:00 (which could be a valid time) 
this one worked for me 

if(!input1.matches("([01]\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\\d"))

Answer (score 0):

```
String inputTimeString = "10:83";
if (!inputTimeString.matches("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$")){
     System.out.println("Invalid time string: " + inputTimeString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function checks only format hh:mm

```
public static boolean isTimeValid(String value) {
    try {
        String[] time = value.split(":");
        return  Integer.parseInt(time[0]) < 24 && Integer.parseInt(time[1]) < 60;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rejects `10:83` alright. Accepts `1:3`, `010:038` and `21:3:p.m.:some:text`.